# Call any class sharing the same method name in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a significant number of classes which share the same method name, but don not share a common base/interface. I cannot touch these classes, however, can I call the method irrespective of the defining class?

Eg:

```
Namespace n1: class A { void M1(n1.CustObj ob1){} }
Namespace n2: class B { void M1(n2.CustObj ob1){} }
```

Would it be possible to abstract from these common methods/parameters, like so?

```
method(Object obj)
{
    obj.M1(new CustObj() { 
        x = 3; 
    }); // CustObj can either belong to n1 or n2
}
```

Comment: Not as you've written it, but you could use reflection to find and call M1 on each object.

Comment: they only share the method name or also the implementation ?

Comment: Is the parameter `CustObj` the same in all implementations?

Comment: You can do this using reflection or the `dynamic` keyword. Not very pretty though.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to define an interface with the method and apply it to these classes.  I'm guessing you can't do this.  Poor design decisions can haunt you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of classes, each of which has a method, with the same name, but with a different signature. The identical method names are a red herring here therefore as they are different methods.

This therefore rules out using `dynamic` or reflection to provide a single method that can handle all of them, unless you then hard-code tests for each type within the one method, or take Jonathan Wood's approach of passing in an existing instance of `CustObj` via a `dynamic` parameter too.

One solution might be to create extension methods for each type:

```
public void Method(this A obj)
{
    obj.M1(new n1.CustObj()
    {
        x = 3
    }); 
}

public void Method(this B obj)
{
    obj.M1(new n2.CustObj()
    {
        x = 3
    }); 
}
```

and so on. Then at least you can do `someObj.Method();` on `A`, `B` and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

You could use either the `dynamic` keyword or reflection.

Of the two, I prefer `dynamic`. However, since your constructor argument is also a different type you'd need to do something like this:

```
void method(dynamic obj, dynamic arg)
{
    arg.x = 3;
    obj.M1(arg);
}
```

I understand it's unlikely that your code is set up to do this but you haven't shown much of how your method is used. And in the end, this might be the best you can do if you're unable to modify the existing classes.

Comment: From the question _I cannot touch these classes_